# Is it Ok to have a reference with incorrect (larger than correct) lifetime in scope?

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe

Does having a reference `&'a T` immediately cause UB (undefined behavior) if `'a` is larger than the referenced value? OR is it fine to have such a reference as long as it does not outlive the referenced value of type `T`?

As a comparison: `mem::transmute::<u8, bool>(2)` is immediate UB, even if you never access the returned value. The same is true if you have a reference with value `0`, because references always have to be valid. Even if you never access them. On the other hand, having `ptr::null()` is not a problem until you try to dereference the null pointer.

Consider this code:

```
let x = '';
let r_correct: &char = &x;

{
    let r_incorrect: &'static char = unsafe { mem::transmute(r_correct) };
    println!("{}", r_incorrect);
}
```

In this code, there are two references to `x`. Neither outlives `x`. But the type of `r_incorrect` is clearly a lie because `x` does not live forever.

Does this code exhibit well defined behavior? I see three options:

- (a) This code exhibits undefined behavior.
- (b) This code's behavior is well defined ("safe").
- (c) Rust has not yet defined the rules about this part of the language.

Comment: I am not sure if [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4fa00faa554289bb9deca2d3b4d935a) can be acceptable as a reference but I am pretty sure it is not safe.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Well, that code does something certainly forbidden: it drops `x` while there are still references to it around. And the compiler doesn't catch that because we lied about the lifetime. But my question is rather about: is merely lying about the lifetime, without doing any other "bad thing", already UB?

Comment: Good point, _if `unsafe` code can be misused by safe code to exhibit undefined behavior, it is unsound._ ([ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html)), so my example shows that it "can be" misused by a safe code(dangling pointer). According to book I guess we can say that your code is safe(with your terms) but unsound.

Comment: @ÖmerErden True, that's a good quote and an answer should certainly mention that. But that's not exactly what the question is about. My question is quite literally about the piece of code in the question. Exactly that. Like, we can run the code and it doesn't crash, yay. But that doesn't mean that behavior is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no official resource explicitly stating whether or not having and/or dereferencing a reference with larger than correct lifetime results in undefined behavior. However, there are multiple resources that talk about undefined behavior in Rust and dereferencing references with unbounded lifetimes that give hints about the definedness of doing this.

## Things causing Undefined Behavior according to Rustonomicon

Quote from [the Rustonomicon, chapter "What Unsafe Can Do"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/what-unsafe-does.html) (**bold highlighting** and *[italic text in brackets]* in this and in all following quotes is by me):

> Unlike C, Undefined Behavior is pretty limited in scope in Rust. All the core
> language cares about is preventing the following things:
>
> - **Dereferencing (using the `*` operator on) dangling or unaligned pointers (see below)**
> - **Breaking the [pointer aliasing rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/references.html)**
> - Calling a function with the wrong call ABI or unwinding from a function with the wrong unwind ABI.
> - Causing a [data race](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/races.html)
> - Executing code compiled with [target features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/codegen.html#the-target_feature-attribute) that the current thread of execution does
>   not support
> - Producing invalid values (either alone or as a field of a compound type such
>   as `enum`/`struct`/array/tuple):
>
>   - *[lots of subitems that are irrelevant to reference lifetimes]*
>
> "Producing" a value happens any time a value is assigned, passed to a
> function/primitive operation or returned from a function/primitive operation.
>
> A reference/pointer is "dangling" if it is null or not all of the bytes it
> points to are part of the same allocation (so in particular they all have to be
> part of *some* allocation). The span of bytes it points to is determined by the
> pointer value and the size of the pointee type. As a consequence, if the span is
> empty, "dangling" is the same as "non-null". Note that slices and strings point
> to their entire range, so it's important that the length metadata is never too
> large (in particular, allocations and therefore slices and strings cannot be
> bigger than `isize::MAX` bytes). If for some reason this is too cumbersome,
> consider using raw pointers.
>
> That's it. That's all the causes of Undefined Behavior baked into Rust. Of
> course, unsafe functions and traits are free to declare arbitrary other
> constraints that a program must maintain to avoid Undefined Behavior.

Only the first two bullet points are related to pointers and/or references.

- The first point is about dereferencing dangling and unaligned pointers.

  - **Unaligned pointers**: Transmuting the lifetime of a reference cannot change its alignedness, so this is not a problem here.
  - **Dangling pointers**: During the correct lifetime, a reference cannot be dangling according to the definition above. Therefore, **during the correct lifetime**, the transmuted reference is also not dangling and can be dereferenced without causing undefined behavior.
- The second point is about the pointer aliasing rules of Rust. Quote from [the Rustonomicon, chapter "References"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/references.html) (which is also linked in the quote above when talking about pointer aliasing rules):

  > There are two kinds of reference:
  >
  > - Shared reference: `&`
  > - Mutable reference: `&mut`
  >
  > Which obey the following rules:
  >
  > - **A reference cannot outlive its referent**
  > - **A mutable reference cannot be aliased**
  >
  > That's it. That's the whole model references follow.
  >
  > Of course, we should probably define what *aliased* means.
  >
  > ```
  > error[E0425]: cannot find value `aliased` in this scope
  >  --> <rust.rs>:2:20
  >   |
  > 2 |     println!("{}", aliased);
  >   |                    ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
  >
  > error: aborting due to previous error
  > ```
  >
  > Unfortunately, Rust hasn't actually defined its aliasing model.
  >
  > While we wait for the Rust devs to specify the semantics of their language,
  > let's use the next section to discuss what aliasing is in general, and why it
  > matters.

  - That first point does indeed not sound that good for our case – "a reference cannot outlive its referent". However, quote from [the Rustonomicon, chapter "Lifetimes", section "The area covered by a lifetime"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html?highlight=outl#the-area-covered-by-a-lifetime):

    > The lifetime (sometimes called a *borrow*) is *alive* from the place it is created to its last use. **The borrowed thing needs to outlive only borrows that are alive**.

    So, as we are not using the reference after the end of the correct lifetime, it is not alive anymore. Therefore, the referent also does not need to be alive after the end of the correct lifetime.
  - The second point is only about **mutable** references – in your example, a shared reference is used. And either way, as long as the original value is not used while the transmuted reference is alive, there is no pointer aliasing going on by any definition (though, as the Rustonomicon says, there is no aliasing model defined for Rust, so language lawyering about this is hard...)

### Conclusion – Things causing Undefined Behavior according to Rustonomicon

The enumeration of things triggering undefined behavior in the Rustonomicon does not contain having and dereferencing a reference with a larger than correct lifetime **as long as this reference is not accessed after the end of the correct lifetime**.

## Things causing Undefined Behavior according to the Rust Reference

The Rustonomicon is not the only documentation talking about undefined behavior. Quote from [the Rust Reference, chapter "Behavior considered undefined"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> Rust code is incorrect if it exhibits any of the behaviors in the following
> list. This includes code within `unsafe` blocks and `unsafe` functions.
> `unsafe` only means that avoiding undefined behavior is on the programmer; it
> does not change anything about the fact that Rust programs must never cause
> undefined behavior.
>
> It is the programmer's responsibility when writing `unsafe` code to ensure that
> any safe code interacting with the `unsafe` code cannot trigger these
> behaviors. `unsafe` code that satisfies this property for any safe client is
> called *sound*; if `unsafe` code can be misused by safe code to exhibit
> undefined behavior, it is *unsound*.
>
> ---
>
> ⚠️ ***Warning:*** The following list is not exhaustive. There is no formal model of
> Rust's semantics for what is and is not allowed in unsafe code, so there may be
> more behavior considered unsafe. The following list is just what we know for
> sure is undefined behavior. Please read the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/index.html) before writing unsafe
> code.
>
> ---
>
> - Data races.
> - **Evaluating a [dereference expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator) (`*expr`) on a raw pointer that is
>   [dangling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#dangling-pointers) or unaligned, even in [place expression context](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions)
>   (e.g. `addr_of!(&*expr)`).**
> - **Breaking the [pointer aliasing rules](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#pointer-aliasing-rules). `&mut T` and `&T` follow LLVM’s scoped
>   [noalias](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#noalias) model, except if the `&T` contains an [`UnsafeCell<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).**
> - Mutating immutable data. All data inside a [`const`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/constant-items.html) item is immutable. Moreover, all
>   data reached through a shared reference or data owned by an immutable binding
>   is immutable, unless that data is contained within an [`UnsafeCell<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).
> - Invoking undefined behavior via compiler intrinsics.
> - Executing code compiled with platform features that the current platform
>   does not support (see [`target_feature`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/attributes/codegen.html#the-target_feature-attribute)).
> - Calling a function with the wrong call ABI or unwinding from a function with the wrong unwind ABI.
> - Producing an invalid value, even in private fields and locals. "Producing" a
>   value happens any time a value is assigned to or read from a place, passed to
>   a function/primitive operation or returned from a function/primitive
>   operation.
>   The following values are invalid (at their respective type):
>
>   - *[lots of subitems that are irrelevant to reference lifetimes]*
>
> ---
>
> **Note:** Uninitialized memory is also implicitly invalid for any type that has
> a restricted set of valid values. In other words, the only cases in which
> reading uninitialized memory is permitted are inside `union`s and in "padding"
> (the gaps between the fields/elements of a type).
>
> ---
>
> **Note**: Undefined behavior affects the entire program. For example, calling
> a function in C that exhibits undefined behavior of C means your entire
> program contains undefined behaviour that can also affect the Rust code. And
> vice versa, undefined behavior in Rust can cause adverse affects on code
> executed by any FFI calls to other languages.
>
> #### Dangling pointers
>
> A reference/pointer is "dangling" if it is null or not all of the bytes it
> points to are part of the same allocation (so in particular they all have to be
> part of *some* allocation). The span of bytes it points to is determined by the
> pointer value and the size of the pointee type (using `size_of_val`). As a
> consequence, if the span is empty, "dangling" is the same as "non-null". Note
> that slices and strings point to their entire range, so it is important that the length
> metadata is never too large. In particular, allocations and therefore slices and strings
> cannot be bigger than `isize::MAX` bytes.

This list, including the two points in **bold**, is more or less equivalent to the list form the Rustonomicon (though a bit less strict, as the first bold bullet point only forbids dereferencing dangling raw pointers, not dereferencing dangling references – I guess this is an oversight). There are a few interesting link to the LLVM documentation, but in the end, the result is the same: Having a reference with a larger than correct lifetime does, according to this list, not result in undefined behavior as long as the reference is not dereferenced after the end of the correct lifetime. However, there is an additional note here:

> ⚠️ ***Warning:*** The following list is not exhaustive. There is no formal model of
> Rust's semantics for what is and is not allowed in unsafe code, so there may be
> more behavior considered unsafe. The following list is just what we know for
> sure is undefined behavior. Please read the [Rustonomicon] before writing unsafe
> code.

### Conclusion – Things causing Undefined Behavior according to the Rust Reference

The Rust Reference does not contain an exhaustive enumeration of all things that can trigger undefined behavior. While the Rust Reference does not explicitely say that references with larger than correct lifetime *do* trigger undefined behavior, it also does not explicitely say that they *don't*.

## Rustonomicon on unbounded lifetimes

Quote from [the Rustonomicon, chapter "Unbounded Lifetimes"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/unbounded-lifetimes.html):

> Unsafe code can often end up producing references or lifetimes out of thin air.
> Such lifetimes come into the world as *unbounded*. The most common source of this
> is dereferencing a raw pointer, which produces a reference with an unbounded lifetime.
> Such a lifetime becomes as big as context demands. This is in fact more powerful
> than simply becoming `'static`, because for instance `&'static &'a T`
> will fail to typecheck, but the unbound lifetime will perfectly mold into
> `&'a &'a T` as needed. However for most intents and purposes, such an unbounded
> lifetime can be regarded as `'static`.
>
> Almost no reference is `'static`, so this is probably wrong. **`transmute` and
> `transmute_copy` are the two other primary offenders. One should endeavor to
> bound an unbounded lifetime as quickly as possible, especially across function
> boundaries.**

The Rustonomicon says that one should "endeavor to bound an unbounded lifetime as quickly as possible, especially across function boundaries". It gives no indication that dereferencing a unbounded reference – assuming that the referent is still alive – would result in undefined behavior. As dereferencing a reference is a common operation, I can't imagine the Rustonomicon not pointing out such an obvious gotcha. I thereby conclude that dereferencing a unbounded reference does not result in undefined behavior as long as the referent is still alive.

However, the question is not about references with unbounded lifetimes, but about references with larger than correct lifetimes, for example a `&'static T`. The Rustonomicon points out that "for most intents and purposes, *[...]* an unbounded lifetime can be regarded as `'static`". This does not definitely imply that dereferencing a reference with larger than correct lifetime is as much defined behavior as dereferencing a reference with an unbounded lifetime. However, I don't see why `rustc` should handle unbounded lifetimes differently in this regard. If it did, I would expect the Rustonomicon to contain a note that it does and that a unbounded lifetime is still safer than a wrongly bound lifetime.

### Conclusion – Rustonomicon on unbounded lifetimes

Dereferencing a *unbounded* lifetime is probably *not* undefined behavior according to the Rustonomicon. This may or may not extend to references with *bound, but larger than correct* lifetimes – in my opinion, it does extend.

## Example on `transmute()` documentation

Quote from the standard library [documentation on `std::mem::transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html#examples), second example:

> Extending a lifetime *[...]*. This is advanced, very unsafe Rust!
>
> ```rust
> struct R<'a>(&'a i32);
> unsafe fn extend_lifetime<'b>(r: R<'b>) -> R<'static> {
>     std::mem::transmute::<R<'b>, R<'static>>(r)
> }
>
> *[...]*
> ```

This is as definitive evidence as you will get that at least *having* a reference with larger than correct lifetime does not result in undefined behavior – otherwise, anyone calling this function with any non-`'static` reference would instantly invoke undefined behavior, and this function would be very, very useless. Additionally, to me this implies that you are also allowed to dereference the references returned by `extend_lifetime` – what would otherwise be the benefit of that function?

### Conclusion – Example on `transmute()` documentation

The example on the `transmute()` documentation seems to imply that dereferencing a reference with a larger than correct lifetime is well defined.

## Final conclusion

Sadly, the documentation on the details of Unsafe Rust is still incomplete, and there are many questions about edge cases like this one that the documentation simply can't give an definitive answer to yet. However, all documentation that is remotely pertinent to the problem seems to imply that dereferencing the reference in question in fact is well-defined behavior. Whether or not this is enough for you to do something like this is up to you – it probably would be for me.

## However, you really shouldn't do this

To clarify: While this code *may* be well defined, it is definitely still a foot gun. Passing such a reference across function borders is a bad idea, especially if the function is `pub` and thereby callable by other modules/crates. Even without passing it across function borders, it is still easy to mis-use this reference, resulting in your code causing undefined behavior. If you think you may need to do this, I urge you to rethink whether you can refactor your code to avoid transmuting the lifetimes. For example, it might be safer (or at least more clear that this is totally and utterly unsafe) to directly use raw pointers instead of references with incorrect lifetimes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is unfortunate that no docs explicitly give an answer to my question, but as you say: most docs imply that my code is not UB, so yeah, that's probably enough for me. Only one thing about your answer: consider removing more irrelevant stuff from the quotes to make the whole answer a bit shorter. But yeah, thanks for your effort!

Comment: You're welcome! You're right, the quotes could be a bit more concise. I'll probably rework this later today if I find time. Thanks for the feedback and the bounty!

Answer (score 6):

No. Undefined Behaviour would only occur if you accessed `r_incorrect` after `x` has gone out of scope, which you are not doing here.

Lifetime annotiations in Rust are *checked* by the compiler to make sure you are not doing anything that would cause memory unsafety but—assuming the borrow checker is happy—they have no impact on the binary that is produced or on how long a variable actually lives.

In your example, you are claiming to the compiler that the lifetime of `r_incorrect` is much longer than it really is, but there is no problem because you only access it within its valid lifetime.

The danger with this is that *future changes* to the code could attempt to use `r_incorrect` beyond its true lifetime. The compiler cannot prevent that from happening because you have already insisted that it's okay.

Comment: "after `r_correct` has gone out of scope" -> You probably meant `x`, right? Also: do you have any sources for this? That the produced binary does not depend on lifetimes? When it comes to `unsafe` stuff, sources are always good :P

Comment: I guess you are really asking the question: "when the compiler sees a static lifetime, does it use that information for optimisations?" I'm not sure this is explicitly written down anywhere but I am certain that the answer will always be "no". The purpose of lifetimes is to prove that borrows are valid or to produce errors if they may not be, and are completely erased before the compiler optimisation steps.

Comment: Rust can and does use lifetime information to perform optimizations. It uses lifetimes to ensure the correctness of various optimizations (like the use of llvm's noalias attributes) and also uses lifetimes for llvm's `lifetime.start` and `lifetime.end` intrinsics. That being said, I believe the code is still well defined so long as `x` isn't mutably borrowed after the `'static` reference is created and no references exist after `x` is freed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: it is UB for a dangling reference to exist, *even if you don't read from it*.

Answer (score 1):

It is sound for a reference to exist with the wrong lifetime *as long as it's not dangling* (as long as the pointed-to value is not deallocated).

You must ensure no references exist to the value before deallocating it. It is UB for a reference to *exist* to a deallocated value, *even if you never read/write to it*. Just it existing is instant UB.

From the reference's [behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> Producing an invalid value, even in private fields and locals [..]:
>
> - A reference or Box that is dangling, unaligned, or points to an invalid value.

It is a common myth that Rust references are "just lifetime-checked pointers". The reality is they're *far more strict*: they must be valid (non-dangling, aligned, pointing to a valid value) for *the entire time they exist*, even if you don't read/write to them. Compare with raw pointers, which only need to be valid when you read/write to them.

It is not UB *per se* to have a reference with the "wrong" lifetime as long as you ensure they're not dangling. Nothing in the [behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) says so. Lifetimes are just a tool for the borrow checker to enforce references are valid, bypassing them with `transmute` is not immediately UB, it just means it's now up to you to ensure all references are valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I awarded the bounty to the other answer since I liked having an overview of basically all relevant docs in one place. Regardless, thanks!