# Is it legal to store a 'static reference to struct internal data in unsafe Rust?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, lifetime, unsafe

I have the following data structure (simplified):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
pub struct StringCache {
    // the hashmap keys point to elements stored in `storage`
    // so never outlive this datastructure. the 'static refs are never handed out
    table: HashMap<&'static str, usize>,

    storage: Vec<Box<str>>,
}
```

Is it legal/*defined behaviour* to "lie" to Rust about the lifetime of the references here? It feels like violating the type system to me.
Is the public API of this data structure sound?
For completeness, here is the full implementation:

```rust
use std::mem::transmute;
impl StringCache {
    pub fn intern(&mut self, entry: &str) -> usize {
        if let Some(key) = self.table.get(entry) {
            return *key;
        }
        let idx = self.storage.len();
        self.storage.push(entry.to_owned().into_boxed_str());
        // we cast our refs to 'static here.
        let key = unsafe { transmute::<&str, &'static str>(&self.storage[idx]) };
        self.table.insert(key, idx);
        idx
    }
    pub fn lookup(&self, idx: usize) -> &str {
        &self.storage[idx]
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: I think the whole your example may be solved just by using `HashSet` instead of `Vec` + `HashMap`, as long as you don't care about order of `str`s.

Comment: @cafce25: I won't argue with related, but it doesn't answer the question. The referenced data here is behind a Box, and will live as long as the struct / reference does.

Comment: @Dmitry: I care about the order, see `fn lookup`

Comment: Then I think it's better to use `Pin<Box<str>>` instead of simple `Box`. There is no overhead, and it's exactly what `Pin` was introduced for.

Comment: @Dmitry: I don't think `Pin` is relevant for the posed question here (would still need the unsafe transmute, could still call `storage.clear()` to get a dangling reference), but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe [`indexmap`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/) solves your problem? If you don't mind an external dependency?

Comment: @isaactfa: this is tagged language-lawyer. I want to know if the code as posed is legal. But thanks for the cool crate recommendation! :)

Comment: Fair enough :) I'm curious too. Transmuting lifetimes is very rarely sound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it Ok to have a reference with incorrect (larger than correct) lifetime in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453911/is-it-ok-to-have-a-reference-with-incorrect-larger-than-correct-lifetime-in-sc)

Comment: Also in general I think it is UB, but in this particular example seems to be not. The thing is that drop order is not defined, so `storage` may be dropped before `table`. Then if `table `drop implementation will use `&'static str` somehow, it will cause UB. Even in this particular example there is no guarantee, that `HashMap` does not use keys somehow whe drops, or will not use in the future.

Comment: @Dmitry: [drop order is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053542/forcing-the-order-in-which-struct-fields-are-dropped)

Comment: FWIW, miri doesn't report undefined behaviour: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=7f326c1b75fae78bd68aa48717c84b23)

Comment: @Dmitry And even if drop order was undefined, `HashMap`'s drop is defined as `#[may_dangle]` and this is observable thus guaranteed.

Comment: If you want to be extra-extra-safe, you can store raw pointers (`*mut str`) in the `Vec` and handle dropping of them yourself.

Comment: @isaactfa You could argue that it **is** unsound in the sense that a future library change (maybe in a fork) can cause undefined behaviour with only safe code by letting a reference with incorrect lifetime escape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This is fine.

---

There are three potential problems here:

1. Creating a reference with lifetime longer than its real lifetime.
2. Moving the type may invalidate the references.
3. While dropping the data we may use the strings after they're dropped.

And none of them is actually a problem. Let's start from the first.

Creating a reference with a lifetime longer than its actual lifetime is *definitely* fine. A lot of code in the wild relies of it to be fine, [it is not listed under "Behavior considered undefined"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#behavior-considered-undefined) in the reference (even though that list is not exhaustive), all current models for code execution in Rust (such as Stacked Borrows or [MiniRust](https://github.com/RalfJung/minirust)) employ this principle (in fact, the very reason for the existence of Stacked Borrows is to not rely on lifetimes for soundness and rather have more fine-grained model), and in [UCG#231](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/231) it was stated that it is obvious that lifetimes cannot affect optimizations, just not specified currently somewhere.

So we're coming to the second issue. The question is whether moving `StringCache` (and therefore, its `storage`) will invalidate the references because it will move the `Vec`'s elements too. Or with more technical terms, whether moving a `Vec` *retags* (a Stacked Borrows term) its elements, asserting their uniqueness.

Your intuition may say that this is fine, but reality is more complicated. `Vec` defines its items with [`Unique`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.69.0/src/core/ptr/unique.rs.html#7-43), which means that by the letter of the law moving it *does* invalidate all existing pointers to elements (this is true about `Box` too). However, lots of code in the wild relies on this to be false, so at least for `Vec` (and perhaps for `Box` too) [we probably want this to be false](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326). I think it is okay to rely on that. Miri does not give `Vec` any special treatement either, and as far as I'm aware, the compiler does not optimize based on it too.

For (3), your current definition (that declares `table` before `storage`) is obviously fine because it drops the `HashMap` first, but even your previous definition (that declared `storage` first) was fine, because [`HashMap` is declared with `#[may_dangle]`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/0.13.2/src/hashbrown/raw/mod.rs.html#1857), meaning it promises it will not access its elements (aside from dropping them) in its drop. This is also a stability guarantee, because it is observable, even in code very similar to yours:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct StringCache<'a> {
    storage: Vec<Box<str>>,
    table: HashMap<&'a str, usize>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut string_cache = StringCache::default();
    string_cache.storage.push("hello".into());
    string_cache.table.insert(&string_cache.storage[0], 0);
}
```

The fact that this code compiles successfully is because `HashMap` promises to not touch its elements during drop. Otherwise, we could have use-after-free. So `HashMap` cannot change this fact suddenly.